# Using Pandas 'categorical' dtype with sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, categorical-data

Is there any support in sklearn to use Panda's *Categorical* datatype directly in fitting models? From what I've seen sklearn does not support this datatype which is unfortunate because the Categorical datatype both encodes categorical data and contains the mapping scheme of the data. In addition categorical encoding is purely a data handling/processing problem so it seems more natural that it would be handled by Pandas.

**Note**

I realize there are several methods to encode categorical variables in Pandas and sklearn - that's not what I'm asking about.

Comment: Note that `categorial` data was added to `pandas` quite recently - when `scikit-learn` was designed that data type did not exist. I am not sure if there's a plan to introduce `categorial` data to scikit-learn - maybe a question only the devs can answer.

Comment: Not only was `categorical` dtype added recently, as @cel already said. But it also does not work very well, even inside pandas, there are lots of things that behave strangely with it. I would suggest to use it with causion and report bugs directly on github.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cross-posting from the [issue-tracker](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4865):

I think these are at least two separate questions:
1. can / will sklearn support pandas dataframes with categorical features as input
2. can / will sklearn support operating on categorical variables via pandas categorical datatypes.

1. would be more or less converting all categorical variables into one-hot encoded features, aka dummy columns. That is really easy to do for the user. We could do that "under the hood" in scikit-learn, but it would complicate the code and I don't see a great benefit.
2. Is basically impossible. Having a categorical datatype would be nice for the trees, but I think pandas has no stable c-level interface, so we can't really tab into that. Even if there was, it would still require a substantial rewrite of the tree code. I don't think it would be helpful for non-tree estimators.

Comment: Ultimately I think that using scikit-learn's **pipeline** module to handle transformations of categorical data is the best solution to my problem since it implicitly keeps track of the encoding.

Comment: I think I'm missing something with ease of use in 1. For multiple columns of categorical variables I'd have to LabelEncode each one separately and then run a OneHotEncoder on each. The other possibility is DictVectorizer on the transposed dataframe (see eg., http://fastml.com/converting-categorical-data-into-numbers-with-pandas-and-scikit-learn/). Both seem not straightforward.

Comment: Ben we want to add string support to OneHotEncoder to make this easier, but we haven't done that yet.

Comment: @AndreasMueller Just saw this response. Just want to +1 this feature. Right now I'm doing all my encoding in pandas which is fine but makes the data frames unnecessarily wide.